# Postgres query returning SQL Error syntax error at "Where"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query, when I execute it I'm getting an error

```
INSERT INTO AM_EVENT_STATUS (EVENT_STATUS_ID, EVENT_ID, TIMESTAMP,OLD_STATUS_ID, NEW_STATUS_ID, NOTE, USERNAME)
SELECT
"external_id" AS EVENT_STATUS_ID,
"external_id" AS EVENT_ID,
"timestamp"   AS TIMESTAMP,
NULL          AS OLD_STATUS_ID,
'unknown'     AS NEW_STATUS_ID,
NULL          AS NOTE,
NULL          AS USERNAME
FROM (SELECT "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"
  FROM "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"
  INNER JOIN (SELECT "external_id", MAX("timestamp") AS "timestamp"
            FROM "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"
              GROUP BY "external_id") LATEST WHERE "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"."external_id" = LATEST."external_id"
    AND "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"."timestamp" = LATEST."timestamp"
    AND "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"."event_type" = 'transaction_update');
```

Error is:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"   Position:
>   601   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or
>   near "WHERE"   Position: 601

What am I doing wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: missing AS: ...) AS LATEST WHERE ...

Comment: tried that didn't work

Comment: John, make sure you explain why adding the correct tag is important instead of dictating something for no reason. It's extremely unprofessional and makes the community look bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `LATEST WHERE` to `LATEST ON`.  You have a `JOIN`, so the correct comparison clause is `ON`, not `WHERE`.

You also need a table alias after the last parentheses.

Comment: nope didn't work.                                                                                       SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
  Hint: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
  Position: 344
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
  Hint: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
  Position: 344

Comment: quick question, i'm trying to select "units_sold" field which is nested inside a jsonb field "custom_fields". How can I access that field ?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO "AM_EVENT_STATUS" ("EVENT_STATUS_ID", "EVENT_ID","TIMESTAMP", "OLD_STATUS_ID", "NEW_STATUS_ID", "NOTE", "USERNAME")
SELECT
"external_id" AS EVENT_STATUS_ID,
"external_id" AS EVENT_ID,
"timestamp"   AS TIMESTAMP,
NULL          AS OLD_STATUS_ID,
'unknown'     AS NEW_STATUS_ID,
NULL          AS NOTE,
NULL          AS USERNAME
FROM (SELECT "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892".*
    FROM "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"
    INNER JOIN (SELECT "external_id", MAX("timestamp") AS "timestamp"
                FROM "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"
                GROUP BY "external_id") AS LATEST 
    ON "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"."external_id" = LATEST."external_id"
    AND "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"."timestamp" = LATEST."timestamp"
    AND "2cba77463c899fee1656b367e39892"."event_type" = 'transaction_update') as EVENTSTATUS;
```